# How nginx proxy to express(node.js)?Why res.data is index.html?

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, proxy

I wrote a Node.js server project by Express framework.It's all right at localhost.But it's have some problem when I build at remote server.(centos 6.5; ngnix 1.11.6; express 4.14.1; node 6.9.5)

1. It's nginx.conf.

   ```
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.cheeseyu.cn cheeseyu.cn;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3009;
        proxy_redirect off; 
    }

    location ~ .*.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|swf|js|css|woff|ttf|TTF|svg)$ {
        root /home/www/blog;
        if (-f $request_filename) {
            expires 100d;
            break;
        }
    }

    error_page 405 =200 @405; 
    location @405 { 
        proxy_method GET;
        proxy_pass http://static_resource;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;
   ```
2. There are info of xhr.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pQmX.jpg)
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmDZO.jpg)
3. It's node.js.

```js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var routes = require('./routes');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.all('', function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With,Content-Type");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","PUT,POST,GET,DELETE,OPTIONS");
    res.header("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");
    next();
});

routes(app);
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3009);
app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

So my question are :

- a. Why status is 200,even I stoped the back-server?
- b. why response data is html(content is index.html)?
- c. why status still is 405,when I use the post?I have tried any
  methods that I finded.
- d. Why status is 200,but after request don't use '.then',but use
  '.catch'?
- e. How nginx proxy to express(node.js)?(I think above all problem is
  nginx didn't proxy request to node server.)

If you want to know details about response,you can visit cheeseyu.cn
Thank you help :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This setting don't have any problem.Just because I reopen nginx,but it no use.You should stop nginx and open nginx

Answer (score 0):

I can show you what i use in nginx conf

```
    location / {
    proxy_pass http://your-domain.com:3009;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

this and a process manager is what i needed to get my first node app running on a server.
As process manager i used stableloop.
Important: U also have to check on witch port your node process is running and fit ur ports to that.

Hope that helps you bit.

(and you have to `$~ service nginx reload` after all changes)